# Will flashing "ADB enable" trigger Knox warranty bit?

Tags: adb, samsung, odin, samsung-knox

I have ghost touch and I am unable to unlock my phone anymore, so I want to flash a file to enable ADB using Odin and then perform a factory reset using ADB... Will it change the KNOX fuse?

File is here: https://zfirmware.com/download-all-samsung-adb-enable-files-removing-security-frp/

Thanks.

Comment: answer: yes. unsigned modified boot.img

Comment: try to override ghost touches: unlock with physical keyboard connected via USB OTG adapter